# Growing vegetables in seedling soil

Tags: vegetables, potting-soil

I am growing some plants on my balcony. I have bought some soil that is marketed as suitable for seedlings and herbs.

I have some lettuce and tomato seedlings germinating in this soil. Soon I will need to move them to a bigger pot.

Can I use the same seedling soil (plus fertilizer?) for growing the vegetables, or will I need to buy a different kind of soil? If different, is general-purpose "flower pot" soil suitable and safe for growing vegetables?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you have.  If it's seed raising mix, then this may not be high in nutrients as it's a sterile medium to allow seeds to germinate without the risk of bacterial or fungal infections.  But some seed raising mixes are higher in nutrient than that, and generally they tend to be more expensive than potting mixes.

So, you should be moving to a potting mix for growing plants in pots. These are free draining to suit pots and have added nutrients for plants.  Some places also sell specific vegetable raising mixes so that the nutrients are biased towards growing vegetables.